finding the minimum and maximum paths in a binary tree C#
Help me  please that will search for the maximum distance (between the farthest leaves) and the minimum distance between the closest leaves in the tree
I understand that the maximum path will have the maximum amount between nodes as it passes, I wrote the code from below, but the problem is that it uses ref and therefore saves the counter values. I do not know how to remove the ref so that it continues to work please help (although I'm not sure if it works right)
public int FindMaxSumPath(Element root, ref int max_sum, ref int additionsCount)
        {
            // tree is null
            if (root == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            // we find the maximum sum of the path from the root to the leaves, starting from the left and right descendant
            int left = FindMaxSumPath(root.Left, ref max_sum, ref additionsCount);
            int right = FindMaxSumPath(root.Right, ref max_sum, ref additionsCount);

            // update sum if we need 
            int currentSum = left + right + Convert.ToInt32(root.Data);
            if (currentSum > max_sum)
            {
                max_sum = currentSum;
                additionsCount++; // counter++
            }

            // return max sum??
            return Math.Max(left, right) + Convert.ToInt32(root.Data); // root.Data is <T>
        }

        // Function to return the maximum count between two leaves in a binary tree
        // It will be used in another class that does not have access to Element root, so it needs to be done without overloads
        public int FindMaxSumPath()
        {
            int max_sum = int.MinValue;
            int count = 0;
            FindMaxSumPath(Root, ref max_sum, ref count);

            return count;
        }

in the picture expect:
blue - max distance
red - min distance
picture expect

I don't understand the example. Surely the closest distance between two distinct leaves is 2: there is a path from 9 to 11.

yes my bad sorry

Why does your code add Data to a sum? It seems unrelated to your question. Does Data have anything to do with your definition of distance?

I see no code that relates to finding the shortest distance between nodes. What is holding you back?

What if the tree consists of just one leaf and a long path from root to that leaf? Is the expected longest path, the one from the root to the leaf, or should it really be a path between two leaves, so that this example has no such path?

Too many things unclear.
